libTIFF: TIFFOpen: test.tif: Cannot open
I tested libTIFF with the CLion builder. However, no matter what I did, it always said I can't open the tiff image... I guess maybe something broken in the find_package(TIFF), so I download the tiff raw source and build it with cmake in the directory C:/Program Files/tiff but still not work.
Here is my cmakelists
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(testTIFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(testTIFF main.cpp)

set(TIFF_DIR C:/Program Files/tiff)
find_package(TIFF REQUIRED)
link_directories(${TIFF_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${TIFF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS "TIFF_INCLUDE_DIRS:" ${TIFF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS "TIFF_LIBRARIES:" ${TIFF_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(testTIFF ${TIFF_LIBRARIES})


Here is the simple source code copied from the TIFF web.
#include <iostream>
#include "tiffio.h"
int main() {
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("test.tif", "r");
    /* ... do stuff ... */
    TIFFClose(tif);
    return 0;
}


and return the null pointer with TIFFOpen... so: TIFFOpen: test.tif: Cannot open.
I just want to read the images, but it never works. I want to know what happened?

Did you try to use an absolute path in your sample code? The current working directory in your test run might not be what you think it is... (as you mentioned CLion).

I changed to use full path as the input argument, rather than the relative path and finally i get the address of the image. Maybe it's the reason of the system?

Thanks a lot! As you mentioned, may be it's the reason of the CLion?

Clion probably compiles the executable in a different directory than the source code. (That's usual for IDEs.) When the debugger is started the directory of the executable is made current directory. Hence, if the test image file is stored in the directory of source code, it won't be found with a relative path "test.tif". This is a common (Sorry) beginners error...

Thanks a lot! I get it... I really don't know it...

Never pass a relative path to a function.  Always convert any relative path to absolute, and pass only absolute paths to functions. Then, when something unexpected happens with a file, print the absolute path of the file that failed to open.  (Which, in all likelihood, is not located there where you thought it would be.)
